# How do I avoild mailgun from disabling my domain if people are spamming me?

Tags: email, mailgun

I'm using mailgun to forward my mail from *@mydomain.com to my gmail account and today my mailgun domain was disabled.

I looked at the logs and saw that I have a lot of incoming spam sent to various @mydomain.com email addresses.  Mailgun was forwarding this mail until today.

How do I get this incoming spam to stop?

Since I'm not sure I can do that, is there any way I can configure mailgun to NOT disable my domains because other people are sending me spam?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set up specific redirects rather than * or take advantage of the "+" trick.
Basically any email address will ignore + and the rest of the string until the @ sign.

For example
bob@gmail.com
and
bob+test@gmail.com

are exactly the same.

Additionally:
I would suggest you'd contact the support team (support@mailgun.com) and by the way make sure the spam filtering is disabled for your domain over here https://mailgun.com/cp/domains

Comment: Contacting support@mailgun.com was the answer... they looked into it and unblocked the domain and loosened the restrictions a little since I'm just forwarding spam to myself instead of other people.